# Getting 301 redirect error in Google Webmaster Tools while using "change address"

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, 301-redirect

So I'm moving my website from one domain to another. In this process I'm using the "change address" function in Google Webmaster Tools on my `old-domain.com`, "switching" it to / choosing my verified `new-domain.com`.

In Step 2 of this process, Google Webmaster Tools **will check whether 301 redirect is setup properly** on `old-domain.com`... And it fails...

Translated to English it says: **"Could not find any 301-redirect directives"**.

I've setup the `301` redirect on my `old-domain.com` in the *.htaccess* - and no other content is in the file than this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.dom/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Am I missing something?

*Note that the redirecting works perfectly*

Comment: Is `old-domain.com` a completely separate hosting account? Are you using a `www` subdomain? `FollowSymLinks` must also be enabled for mod_rewrite to function, if it's not already.

Comment: Yup, old-domain.com is on a completely different hosting account and im not using any subdomains. I havent defined any FollowSymLinks in my .htaccess - is it important? Redirect of urls are working fine

Comment: Ah, if redirecting is working OK (sorry, missed that) but Google is reporting an error then are you sure that Google is not requesting `www.old-domain.com` (ie. _with_ the subdomain)?

Comment: Yup - since there are no subdomains, that would not be possible :). The domain is within webmaster tools defined as: old-domain.com

Comment: I even followed the suggestion of .htaccess here: http://joomlaseo.com/Blog/changing-domain-url-using-301-redirect - where he afterwards does the exact same thing changing address. Still the same error with my account :(

Comment: confirm your new site properly added in webmaster and sitemap added successfully.
I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your .htaccess actually looks OK, and you say the redirection is working OK for you. The only possibility is that if Google is requesting the `www` subdomain? In this case, Google would not see the redirect since you are specifically checking for the bare domain.

Since your `old-domain` is a separate hosting account then your directives can be simplified (ie. no need to check the requested HOST, since it can only be `old-domain` anyway), and this will also capture the `www` subdomain (if that is indeed the problem)...

All that's required is:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://new-domain.dom/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In Webmaster tools, I can see under "settings for old-domain.com" that it is defined as "show website as my-domain.com" = not with "www". I'll try your suggested approach and see if that helps :)

Comment: And the validated domain in GWT is `old-domain.com`, not `www.old-domain.com`? If so then there should be no reason why Google can't see this redirect.

Comment: Everywhere in GWA it's listing with old-domain.com. The account added also just shows with old-domain.com and as a test I just added the account with www.old-domain.com (which you need to do the first time when changing the setting to "show website as my-domain.com"). Removed the "www." account again - but no luck yet. Indeed very weird. I'll keep on the fight

Comment: Just a thought, is the `new-domain` validated in  GWT, and what validation method are you using?

Comment: Yup, new domain validated and confimed by .html file :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you are adding a domain in Google Webmaster Tools, use the domain as `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`. 
This will also cause 301 error when you revamp or migrate the site.

If you have already added `example.com` then also add this too `www.example.com` and verify it in webmaster tools.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "This will also cause 301 error".   Adding properties to GWT never causes your site to 301 redirect, and redirects are not "errors"

Comment: I mean just use www.example.com instead of example.com while adding the property in google webmaster tools

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess is fine and mabye working, but the correct way is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Because google will chek both www and non www protocols.

Once you make this change, please chek it if works fine with this tool: http://web-sniffer.net/

After you validate the step 2, I warn you, step 3 may fail depending on the validation method you had for webmasters tools. To resolve this, you will have to re-validate your old domain by using a configuration option in your DNS (acseso to your service ISP provider's option). Webmasters tools will give you a code when you choose that option, and will ask you to create a TXT record in your DNS settings.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Thorma - thanks for contributing - appreciate it! I will need to keep the same url structure from old-domain.com - right now with the above - it seems everything will just redirect to new-domain.com - like: old-domain.com/subdir/ should redirect to new-domain.com/subdir/ etc., but doesn't seem to do so with the above?

Comment: Bit of an aside, but... there is no need to escape slashes or dots in the `RewriteRule` substitution (or surround it in quotes) since it is an ordinary string, not a regex.